# Avada Theme - Submenu customization 2

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I have got the same problem as like the guy in this topic: [Avada Theme - Submenu customization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29277034/avada-theme-submenu-customization/43845501?noredirect=1#comment74726726_43845501), but I just can't find the side-navigation CSS styles where I've to change the code.

I already put the code into the Avada theme options CSS editor but nothing changed.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question. Did you know there is a whole separate stack exchange just for word press?

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that your css code is correct then put it in the WP Dashboard > Appearance > Theme Options > Custom CSS field and Save.

https://theme-fusion.com/knowledgebase/how-to-make-custom-css-changes/